# Format HTML page according to PHP array

Tags: php, sorting, logic

I have an unsorted and dynamically changing array in php where I have values stored as in "blue", "red", "green". The rest of the array consists of strings like "wet", "dry", "humid". Now I want to print respective titles before printing the strings to my html page. How can I achieve this?

Above code produces problems since if else fires, before all three colors have been echoed out, it will print the heading again.

Edit:

Array: blue, humid, green, wet, dry, red.

```
echo "<h3>Color</h3><br>";
foreach($array as $value){
if ($value == "blue" || $value == "red" || $value == "green") {
    echo $value;
}
echo "<h3>Weather</h3><br>";
foreach($array as $value){
if ($value != "blue" || $value != "red" || $value != "green") {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: What are `respective titles`?

Comment: <h1>Color</h1> and <h2>Weather</h2>.

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide us with your array structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself. Changing the logical ORs in the second foreach loop does print out only the weather conditions as expected.

```
echo "<h3>Color</h3><br>";
foreach($array as $value){
if ($value == "blue" || $value == "red" || $value == "green") {
    echo $value;
}
echo "<h3>Weather</h3><br>";
foreach($array as $value){
if ($value != "blue" && $value != "red" && $value != "green") {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: well done, now you can mark it as an answer - nothing wrong with that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because your boolean expression isn't correct. It should be

```
if($file == 'blue' || $file == 'red' || $file == 'green')
```

The way you've written it it will be equal to

```
if($file == 'blue' || true || true)
```

And with the logical `OR` the expression is `TRUE` if only one of the variables equals `TRUE`.
**Edit**
On a second reading, `echo` the heading before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: yea I know about the boolean expression, sorry for that, it is not the issue here. The point is that the script WORKS FINE - but the if the array is UNSORTED, it does produce the heading more than once. I need to sort the thing before hand and split it into 2 different arrays I guess.

Comment: @StephanKristyn With the code you *have* shown, this certainly is an issue. As for the rest of your code; how are we to know?? You didn't show it.

Comment: Echoing the (colors) heading before the foreach won't help either, in case the array is unsorted, think about it. Item's will get left out and then get printed without (colors) heading after the second (weather) heading was printed in the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

`if` statement syntax is wrong. It needs to be `if ($file == "blue" || $file == "red" || $file == "green") {`

echo the heading `echo "<h1>Colours</h1>";` before the foreach loop, like this:

```
       echo "<h1>Colours</h1>";      
       foreach($file_list as $file) {

      if ($file == "blue" || "red" || "green") {        
         echo $file;
        }
      else { ...}
```

Comment: <h2>Weahter</h2> prints in else condition, but if green hasn't been echoed yet, you will have a problem.

Comment: you would need to show the entire code(atleast the `if-else` statement), for us to figure out your question. Also, the structure for `$file_list`